# Upper bound for |f(z)|

Tags: complex-analysis

The question is:

Let $f$ be analytic in the unit disc $\mathbb D$ satisfying $f(0)=1$ & $Re (f(z)) \gt |Im(f(z))|$ , $\forall z \in \mathbb D$ . Then show that : $|f(z)|^{2} \leq \frac {1+|z|}{1-|z|}$.

Thank You.

I am thinking of using Schawarz Lemma; but not sure if it is the right way OR how to use it at all.

Comment: Make a picture (mental or on paper) of the set $A$ characterised by the inequality $\operatorname{Re} w > \lvert \operatorname{Im} w\rvert$. Then think what set $B = \{w^2 : w \in A\}$ is. Then think about the Schwarz lemma.

Comment: The set of $w$ satisfying $Re (w) \gt |Im(w)|$ is the sector below the line $y=x$ in the first quadrant . & then B should be the first quadrant . Right??

Comment: That's not all of $A$, there's more. But you're going in the right direction.

Comment: Oops!! Sorry... Thanks..I missed the portion in the $2$nd Quadrant...So , as $B$ ; I got the whole upper half plane $\mathbb H$. But my doubt is ... I mean how to use Schwarz Lemma there?? .. ( I hope you are not referring to Schwarz Reflection Principle!)

Comment: If you get the second quadrant and upper half-plane, you draw your plane uncanonically. But a half-plane you get. Now, for the Schwarz lemma, you want a function with values in the unit disk, such that $h(0) = 0$. How would you go about that?

Comment: Firstly, I didn't get that phrase " you draw your plane uncanonically" ... & answering the second one: I will look for the Fractional Linear Transformation mappin $\mathbb H$ to $\mathbb D$ , sending $0$ to $0$.

Comment: In the conventional way to draw the plane, $A$ has parts in the first and _fourth_ quadrant, and $B$ is the _right_ half-plane [right as opposite of left, not as opposite of wrong]. So if you get the upper half-plane, you must draw your plane in a different way. The fractional linear transformation is good, but you're using the wrong normalisation, it should map $f(0)^2$ to $0$.

Comment: Sorry... first part is clear; but I am not getting the second part somehow. Please give a detailed proof for that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption, $f$ maps the unit disk into the set

$$A = \left\{w\in\mathbb{C} : \operatorname{Re} w > \lvert \operatorname{Im} w\rvert\right\} = \left\{ w \in \mathbb{C} : - \tfrac{\pi}{4} < \arg w < \tfrac{\pi}{4}\right\}.$$

Hence $g(z) = f(z)^2$ maps $\mathbb{D}$ into the right half-plane. And $g(0) = f(0)^2 = 1^2 = 1$. So

$$h(z) = \frac{g(z)-1}{g(z)+1}$$

is a holomorphic function $h\colon \mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}$ with $h(0) = 0$. Now you can apply the Schwarz lemma to $h$, and then deduce from that that

$$\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant \frac{1+\lvert z\rvert}{1-\lvert z\rvert}$$

for $z\in\mathbb{D}$.